# is given. prove that there is 3 numbers a, b, c that: $0.5<$a^2/bc<2 using pigeonhole principle.(n>2)

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

$2n-1$ numbers from 
{${1, 2, 3, ...,2^n-2}$}
is given. prove that there is 3 numbers a, b, c that:
$0.5<$a^2/bc<2
using pigeonhole principle.(n>2) we do not know which numbers selected. a, b, c are distinct numbers.

Comment: @quasi WE DO NOT KNOW WHICH NUMBER SELECTED!!!

Comment: My mistake, I msread the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing $a,b,c$ must be distinct numbers? Otherwise pick $a=b=c$, then $\frac{a^2}{bc}=1$.

Comment: @IsaacRen yes, they are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k\in\{1,...,n-1\}$, let $X_k=\{2^k-1,...,2^{k+1}-2\}$.

Every element of $\{1,...,2^n-2\}$ lies in exactly one of the sets $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$,
hence by the pigeonhole principle, of the $2n-1$ selected numbers, at least one of those sets, $X_k$ say, contains at least $3$ of the selected numbers.

Thus suppose $X_k$ contains the $3$ selected numbers $a,b,c$ with $b < a < c$.$\;$Then
$$
\frac{1}{2}
=
\frac{2^k-1}{2^{k+1}-2}
\le
\frac{b}{c}
=
\frac{b^2}{bc} < 
\frac{a^2}{bc} <
\frac{c^2}{bc}
=
\frac{c}{b}
\le
\frac{2^{k+1}-2}{2^k-1}
=
2
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)